# Vue 3 migrate modifiers by condition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I continues migrate to vue 3.
In vue 2 i use method by @pbastowski for add modifiers by condition for input

```
<input type="text" v-model="filter" @[isOpen&&click.stop] />
```

how can i do in vue 3 it ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything special for Vue3. Just check the condition, then make the method call

```
<input type="text" v-model="filter" @click.stop="isOpen && yourMethodCall($event)" />
```

Comment: Your code always bind a `click`-handler, while the OP's code does it conditionally (at least that seems to be the intention).

Comment: Hmm.. I see. I don't really understand OP's use case, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

oh i find problem thx @j-titus.

1. my question was that old syntax dont work in vue 3
2. i havent my handler
3. if i try

@click.stop="isOpen"

```
 i receive error 
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:218 Uncaught TypeError: $setup.isOpen is not a function
```

4. but its work without error:

@click.stop="isOpen == true"

Comment: Ah, okay. Great. Glad that it helped you find your problem.

Comment: `@click.stop="isOpen == true"` does nothing. Did you mean to set `isOpen` to `true`?

Comment: @tony19 if you have solution better -> write

Comment: The code's purpose is unclear, so I can't provide a solution. What is that code supposed to do? Can you share a link to a demo (e.g., in StackBlitz or Codepen) of that working in Vue 2?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).